I have issue in flutter with error RealtimeSubscribeException
I always receive an error

RethrownDartError: RealtimeSubscribeException(status: RealtimeSubscribeStatus.channelError, details: RealtimeCloseEvent(code: 1000, reason: ))

here is my code so far what I did.
I can not find solution. I think the issue in stream
class ScheduleApi {
  final SupabaseClient _supabaseClient;

  ScheduleApi(this._supabaseClient);

  Stream<List<BranchesModel>> fetchBranches() {
    try {
      return _supabaseClient
          .from('branches')
          .stream(primaryKey: ['id'])
          .order('name', ascending: true)
          .map((event) {
            final branchesList = event
                .map(
                  (e) => BranchesModel.fromJson(e),
                )
                .toList();
            if (branchesList.isEmpty) {
              throw 'No Branches Found';
            }
            return branchesList;
          });
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }


class BranchesBloc extends Bloc<BranchesEvent, BranchesState> {
  final FetchBranchesUsecase _fetchBranchesUsecase;
  StreamSubscription<List<BranchesEntity>>? _streamSubscription;
  BranchesBloc(
    this._fetchBranchesUsecase,
  ) : super(const _Loading()) {
    on<BranchesEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await event.when(
        stream: () async {
          try {
            if (_streamSubscription != null) {
              await _streamSubscription!.cancel();
            }
            _streamSubscription = _fetchBranchesUsecase().listen(
                (branchesList) => add(
                      BranchesEvent.update(branchesList),
                    ),
                onError: (error) =>
                    add(BranchesEvent.failed(error.toString())));
          } catch (e) {
            emit(BranchesState.failed(e.toString()));
          }
        },
        update: (branchesList) async {
          emit(BranchesState.loaded(branchesList));
        },
        failed: (error) async {
          emit(BranchesState.failed(error.toString()));
        },
      );
    });
  }
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _streamSubscription!.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}

I think the error in bloc in supabase
